# Get details semester wise highest marks without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

```
Student (Roll_id,Student_name)
Student_mark (roll_id, semester, marks, subject)
```

I want student details who has got highest marks IN semester AND subject wise WITH their roll_id,mark,semester,subject
using that two table.

can we get results without using cursor?.

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output. Also, add what database system you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.) and what queries you have tried.

Comment: I am using sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RANK()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function to put the students in order by mark (partitioned by semester and subject):

```
WITH RankedResults AS
(   SELECT  s.Roll_ID,
            s.Student_Name,
            sm.Semester,
            sm.Subject,
            sm.Marks,
            StudentRank = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY sm.Semester, sm.Subject ORDER BY sm.Marks DESC)
    FROM    Student s
            INNER JOIN Student_Mark sm
                ON s.Roll_ID = sm.Roll_ID
)
SELECT  Roll_ID, Student_name, Semester, Subject, Marks
FROM    RankedResults
WHERE   StudentRank = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c83ce/1)**